# Getting the QPainter drawtext color change with with shader

Tags: qt, opengl

I used the `QPainter` to draw text and its working fine, Then I added OpenGL shader to this. But I couldn't change the color of the text using the shader.

This is the `QPainter drawText` code

```
program.bind();
QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&device);
QColor fontColor = QColor(1, 1, 1);

painter.setPen(fontColor);

QFont font;
font.setPointSize(24);
painter.setFont(font);


painter.drawText(drawRect, "Hello", QTextOption(Qt::AlignCenter));

painter.end();

program.release();
```

Here color is set to white and in shader simply set the color to red color.

Final out put is always the color set in the QPainter and not the color in the shader.

Can't we use shaders to do changes to the `QPainter drawText` function output ?

Comment: By 'shader' you're referring to an OpenGL shader, correct?  Shaders only affect the OpenGL state and have nothing to do with the `Qt` painting implementation.

Comment: @G.M. thank you for comment, I updated the question and yes I'm referring to OpenGL shaders. Isn't the QPainter drawtext using OpenGL for drawing text ?

Comment: Even if `Qt` is using OpenGL for the rendering backend it will keep its own state separate from that of OpenGL.  Consider, for example, a fairly complex shader program that generates multiple outputs that can be used in later rendering passes -- `Qt` has no way of knowing the intended use of the outputs.  In short, there are lots of reasons why keeping the `Qt` paint engine state separate from the OpenGL state is a good thing.